CSV file importation with python plugins
I wrote this code in order to import layer in the view with a csv with POINT Z et LINESTRING Z lines. Manually the csv is well imported but there is no coordinate system defined. I usuall slide it to the layer menu and the layer are well imported with the same csv.
uri = f"file:///{file_path}?delimiter=%3B&wktField=WKT&geomType=auto&skipEmptyFields=Yes"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Couche Importée", "delimitedtext")
layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem())
if not layer.isValid():
  QMessageBox.critical(None, "Erreur", "Well imported.")
  return
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

Before that, the csv is read by the code and modified.
I expect the layer import themself thanks to the code just as I slide them.

Hi, Welcome to SE. But it seems your question is not very well-defined. Can you be a bit more precise regarding your query? Thank you.
